# Как передать файл по локальной сети Windows -> Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, локальная-сеть

Не подскажете **библиотеку** для бесконтактной передачи файла с одного *Windows* на другой по **локальной сети**?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Спасибо большое! Побежал глядеть.